# How to set the content-type header to nothing?

Tags: php, http, http-headers

I want to make a POST request : `http://NUXEO_SERVER/nuxeo/api/v1/upload/`

There is no data to send , but this webservice needs a POST method. So how to set the `Content-type` of the header ?

This is my code :

```
$nuxeoBatchId = file_get_contents('http://192.168.128.101/nuxeo/api/v1/upload/', false, stream_context_create([
                  'http' => [
                              'method' => 'POST',
                              'header'  => "Content-type: text/html",
                              'content' => http_build_query([]) // of form 'key1' => 'Hello world!', 'key2' => 'second value'
                            ]
                   ])
                 );
$response->setContent($nuxeoBatchId);
return $response;
```

Comment: What's the error now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec7.html#sec7.2.1:

> Any HTTP/1.1 message containing an entity-body SHOULD include a
> Content-Type header field defining the media type of that body. If and
> only if the media type is not given by a Content-Type field, the
> recipient MAY attempt to guess the media type via inspection of its
> content and/or the name extension(s) of the URI used to identify the
> resource. If the media type remains unknown, the recipient SHOULD
> treat it as type "application/octet-stream".

I think if you don't know media type, you should just skip `Content-Type` or set to `application/octet-stream`

Comment: ...current spec is RFC 7231, though.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no payload to send, then you shouldn't set a Content-Type header field at all.